# How to import csv file locally for mapping but NOT inside the current SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, import

The only import method I know:

[image]

**Problem**: it imports the `.csv` file into current server which is not allowed in the security policy, blocked.

**Goal**: simply import table for mapping some info which the current server doesn't have.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM Server_Table1
INNER JOIN Import_CSV_Table ON Server_.ID = Import_CSV_Table.ID;
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear but... do you mean import into a different SQL Server? You should be able to choose a target SQL Server in the wizard

Comment: Thank you Nick , its similar . But how about import csv file in SSMS but not belong to any server ? Like import file when you are running Python or R.The problem in my case is the current server is not allowed to import any file regard as the security constraint . I need a method to import the CSV which no need to consider the security constraint

Comment: There is a communication issue here. Can you post the error that you get? I don't understand what you mean by "import csv file in SSMS but not belong to any server "

Comment: "Problem: it imports the .csv file into current server". No it imports the data into the server that you tell it to import into. On the second page of the wizard you "choose a destination". That can be any SQL Server that you have access to

Comment: Thank you , i do need some flat document to learn how to import .

Comment: 1. Have you been successful in importing the file into a table? 2. If not, what error do you get? 3. Are you trying to import into a specific SQL Server? If so, what happens when you use the wizard to import into it?

Comment: In "Choose a Destination" ,1 - choose any " Net Framework Provider XXX"  return Error :"connection string property has not been initialized." ---> Its relies on Windows Authentication . 2 - choose "SQL Server native Client 11.0"  but i login server by "universal with mfa support " login , no login info. for inputting "Authentication" blank . cannot go to the next page . Thats why i am curious is it possible to simply import into SSMS the tools itself but not any server.

Comment: I think I understand maybe... no it's not possible to import into just SSMS. It's a client tool to a database. Without a database it doesn't do anything. But it's really quite simple to install SQL Express (free) on your computer and use that database.

Comment: Thank you Nick , its definitely a solution . In many situation you have to customize with own master file but not manipulate directly with main company database in the server . Since only "universal with mfa support " login is allowed , you do not own an login ID to retrieve data through R or Python to customize with local master file. Its a difficult case